# RealTek RTL8821AE under Kubuntu

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, bluetooth, realtek

I've just bought a Gigabyte Brix pro to make a small portable NAS. I've installed Kubuntu 14.10 on it.

Unfortunately I've got some trouble with WiFi. Its on RealTek RTL8821AE chip. When I look at the log, the WiFi driver is switching between the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz channel all the time.

I was able to connect to a 2.4Ghz channel once, but the connection failed after a while, it recognizes my 5Ghz channel (moxWifi 5 Ghz) once, but never connected, and after a while, got some trouble with the space in the name - so I've changed it (moxWifi5Ghz) with no improvement.

For the moment I'm blocked.

PS : I also have some trouble with the Bluetooth, I'm able to connect the mouse but not the keyboard ...

Answer (score 1):

I have a laptop with a similar problem. Almost all linux distributions i have used have a problem with the RTL8821AE wireless network card. This repository contains software to help you solve this issue

https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi

I will not vouch for any software from anywhere including this. I use it despite this.

I cant help with the keyboard though...